# Angular testing an edit service with parameters

Tags: angular, testing, integration-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a component which gets an id params and calls a service with this data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.provider = this.activatedRoute.params
    .subscribe( params => (
          this.dataService.getProvider(params['id']).subscribe( (data:any) => {
           this.provider = data;
         })
    ));
  }
```

I want to test if getProvider is called so I create a test like this

```
it('should call getProvider service', () => {

    const activatedRoute:ActivatedRouteStub = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
    activatedRoute.push({ id: 1 }); //set the id value for params

    const service = TestBed.get(DataService);
    const spy = spyOn(service,'getProvider').and.returnValue(of({id:1, name: 'Gabriela' }));

    component.ngOnInit(); //initialize component 

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); //check if service is called
  });
```

first setting the param id and then do an spy to check the service is called.

But I'm always getting an error message

```
Expected spy getProvider to have been called.
```

My issue is because getprovider is inside the other subscribe. If I remove the first subscriber to get the id param , all is working fine.

Comment: An easy proposal would be to just put `activatedRoute.push({ id: 1 });` line after the `component.ngOnInit();`. If it doesn't htlp then could you please provide code of `ActivatedRouteStub` I think problem lies there.

Comment: Yes, if you provide your whole test suite, I think I/we can help you better and like Andrei said, the problem most likely lies in the `ActivatedRouteStub`.

Comment: Thanks Andrei,  it was the solution anyway why it's working like this. First ngOnInit and then setup the param?